Why are we getting a different answer on using the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem?
If $C$ is the circle $|z| = 2$ taken with positive orientation, then
$
\int_C \frac{2z \, dz}{z^2 + 2} = 4\pi i.
$
The solution given in the book goes like this:
Solution Using partial fractions, the integral given can be written as
$
\int_C \frac{2z \, dz}{z^2 + 2} = \int_C \frac{dz}{z + i\sqrt{2}} + \int_C \frac{dz}{z - i\sqrt{2}}.
$
Since the points $z = \pm i\sqrt{2}$ lie interior to $ C $, we note that,
$
\int_C \frac{dz}{z \pm i\sqrt{2}} = 2\pi i.
$
The results in above can be used to conclude that
$
\int_C \frac{2z \, dz}{z^2 + 2} = 2\pi i + 2\pi i = 4\pi i.
$

Now, Cauchy-Goursat Theorem (CGT) says,

Let $f$ be analytic in a simply
connected domain $D.$ If $C$ is a simple closed contour that lies in $D,$ the $\int_C f(z)dz = 0.$

We must also note that,
CGT is valid for regions that aren't simply connected as well.
I found the above statement to be valid in the book named, "Complex Variables" by Schaum's Outline Series (2nd Edition). I am attaching a picture of that piece of text from the book, in here for reference purposes:

Now, coming back to the problem given,
$\exists$ a domain $D$ that contains curve $C$ and excludes the two points $\pm i\sqrt 2$ such that $D$ is multiply connected.
Then, as $f$ is analytic in $D$ so we have, $\int _C f(z)dz=0.$
But this is not the answer that's found in the above solution.
Why are we getting this different answer on applying CGT? Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

There is no such simply connected domain $D$.

'CGT is valid for regions that aren't simply connected as well': Not true.

@geetha290krm Thanks for pointing out the typo! I meant $\exists$ a multiply connected domain $D.$ But in the book by Schaum Series on Complex Analysis it's given that CGT is valid for multiply connected regions as well. So is that incorrect?

@MartinR  In the book by Schaum Series on Complex Analysis it's given that CGT is valid for multiply connected regions as well. So is that incorrect? I have attached a picture of the same in the original post. You might want to check that out.

of course the Cauchy theorem is valid for a domain excluding the poles, but it involves integration on the full boundary which will consist of two curves generally so it just says that the integral on the circle is equal to the integral on another curve that also encloses the poles

You should be able to verify the picture "theorem" is wrong for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ on the punctured unit disc.  The correct full statement for Cauchy Goursat is that it is valid "only for cycles which are null-homologous"  [i.e. using Artin's winding number criterion].  You are not going to get this from Schaums but would get it from a book like Ahlfors, Beardon or Ash & Novinger.
